# OpenSSL issue with RSA_public_encrypt

Tags: delphi, openssl, rsa

I've got an issue with encrypting with RSA_public_encrypt.

What I have: modulus (1024 bit), exponent (everytime they do not change) and plaintext.

What I want: encrypt the plain text using public key made of modulus and exponent (which are passed as HEX-string) with RSA_PKCS1_OAEP_PADDING.

The problem is that RSA_public_encrypt function trows access violation and I don't understand why. I've seen lots of similar examples on the Internet but they seem to fine due to the comments.

Here's my code:

```
procedure RSAPublicEncrypt(const PlainText, Modulus, Exponent: AnsiString);
  var
    PublicKey: pRSA;
    Output: Integer;
    BN_Modulus, BN_Exponent: pBIGNUM;
    Res: AnsiString;
  begin
    Result := '';
    try
      PublicKey := RSA_new(); //Creating new key

      PublicKey^.n := BN_new; //Creating new modulus
      Output := BN_hex2bn(PublicKey^.n, PAnsiChar(Modulus)); //Convert modulut from hex to BIGNUM

      PublicKey^.e := BN_new; //same to the exponent
      BN_hex2bn(PublicKey^.e, PAnsiChar(Exponent));

      //Trying to encrypt. Here I get the AV
      Output := RSA_public_encrypt(Length(PlainText), PAnsiChar(PlainText), PAnsiChar(Res), PublicKey, RSA_PKCS1_OAEP_PADDING);
    finally
      BN_clear_free(PublicKey^.e);
      BN_clear_free(PublicKey^.n);
      RSA_free(PublicKey);
    end;
  end;
```

What am I doing wrong? Help me please. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I've found the source of the problem. It was the wrong implementation of RSA structure. It was missing one pointer:

```
RSA = record
    pad: integer;
    version: integer;
    meth: pRSA_METHOD;
    engine: pointer; //<-- this one was missing
    n: pBIGNUM;
    e: pBIGNUM;
    d: pBIGNUM;
    p: pBIGNUM;
    q: pBIGNUM;
    dmp1: pBIGNUM;
    dmq1: pBIGNUM;
    iqmp: pBIGNUM;
    ex_data: CRYPTO_EX_DATA;
    references: integer;
    flags: integer;
    _method_mod_n: pBN_MONT_CTX;
    _method_mod_p: pBN_MONT_CTX;
    _method_mod_q: pBN_MONT_CTX;
    bignum_data: ^byte;
    blinding: ^BN_BLINDING;
end;
```

Answer (score 0):

Res is not initialised, but you are writing to it. I assume a typo and that line

```
Result := '';
```

really should be

```
Res := '';
```

If this is so then there is not enough room to hold your result, and you need to use something like SetLength to Res to make it big enough to hold the result plus a null terminator.

```
SetLength( Res, Length(PlainText) + 1); // or whatever is appropriate
```

You need to be aware that AnsiString is reference counted and automatically controlled like a normal string, but PAnsiChar is not, and is considered a predefined string that does not change its size (memory allocated) automatically. When you cast AnsiString to PAnsiChar, internally the the compiler passes a pointer to the first char of the AnsiString, bypassing its reference count and length fields. It is NOT changing Res into an AnsiChar Array. Therefore it must be used with great care.

Another way would be to define Res as an array of AnsiChar

```
Res : Array[0..255] of AnsiChar;
```

for instance, which explicitly shows the memory allocated, but setting the length is more flexible.